# Nashorn: concurrent eval with singleton ScriptEngine ? thread safe?

Tags: multithreading, servlets, nashorn

We would like to use Nashorn within a servlet. The idea is to use a singleton instance of ScriptEngine that is reused at every request.  At each request an new EngineScope Binding is created, and the eval is run with that binding.  Then the binding is cleared.  No shared objects are passed to the bindings (just the request/response objects from the servlet).

Within the servlets, the singleton instance of ScriptEngine may be eval-ed concurrently in different threads, will this work properly or will it run into a threading issue?  Here is some code that gives the idea:

```
ScriptEngine engine = getNashornSingleton();

ScriptContext newContext = new SimpleScriptContext();
newContext.setBindings(engine.createBindings(), ScriptContext.ENGINE_SCOPE);
Bindings engineScope =newContext.getBindings(ScriptContext.ENGINE_SCOPE);

engineScope.put("request", request);
engineScope.put("response", response);

engine.eval(jsCode, engineScope);
engineScope.clear();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My answer to my own question: I would not use a singleton as described above.  Despite some potential threading issues, you likely do not want to destroy the bindings at each request (as it may require re-compiling of scripts).  What we ended up doing is creating a pool of Engines and their associated scope Bindings.  An engine/binding pair.

At each servlet request we grab an engine/binding pair from the pool, put the request/response into the binding, and then execute the script.  There is no threading issues to worry about because a given engine/binding pair is only executed by a single thread at a time.  When the request is done, the engine/binding pair is returned to the pool.  Seems to work well.

Comment: I'm just wondering if you could give a bit more detail on your setup. We have had similar concurrency issues with Nashorn in a webapp (server-side rendering with React). We have tried wrapping the engine in a ThreadLocal but performance was very poor. We are now experimenting with CompiledScript and Invocable.

How big is your pool? I suppose if you get no of requests equals to thread pool size you will hit issues...

Comment: I opted for a pool of nashorn engines.  My first attempt was to just have a pool of engines, and re-create fresh bindings each time (but this seemed to force re-compiling of the nashorn scripts each time the script is invoked.  So, I created a wrapper object that keeps the engine and its associated binding.  This does not require a script to be re-compiled each time the servlet calls the same script.  Once the servlet is finished, the wrapper object is returned to the pool.

Comment: A reaper thread is called every so often that desttroys unused engine/bindings.  The performance is good enough.  Slightly slower than a regular servlet, but good.  There are a lot of little details about how to load the scripts from file without re-compiling.  I am thinking about open sourcing it, what do you think?

Comment: The nsahorn sripts do nto run is a separate thread, but in the same thread as the servlet thread.  So, no need to worry about each request adding more threads.  The pool is not of threads, but are of nashorn engines/bindings which are reused.

Comment: about the pool size, it grows dynamically.  If there are no engines idle engines int he pool, it creates a new engine and adds it to the pool.  The pool can get big, but that is no big deal.  They will eventually be collected by the reaper thread once the load goes down.

Comment: The wrapper object is an interesting approach but I'm not sure it will work for me. I'm going to have a look this afternoon. Open sourcing it sounds good - I would be interested to look at - and would be happy to contribute if I tweaked in anyway for my setup.

Comment: Why can't you bind a cache of CompiledScript s to your threadlocal ? This would avoid the recompilation part. Each servlet thread will be associated with a threadlocal script cache of your compiled scripts.

Comment: using a thread local would work too (and it ultimately similar to using a pool).

Comment: @adamM Have you open sourced it meanwhile? I would be **very** interested!

Comment: @bgraves no I have not opened sourced it.  As my project proceeded, the code started to gather lots of pieced that were specific to our use case, not generalized code.  I could separate out the parts and open source in the future, but it would take a bit of work (but work that might be fun).  However, the method I described works well and has been used in production for over a year.